# Windows 10 Lock/Logon Screen Image through GPO

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I'm trying to set the Windows 10 lock screen universally on a computer to a predefined image. To do this I'm using the GPO "Force a specific default lock screen image". This policy is Enabled and directed to a jpg located on a network location.

My problem is this policy doesn't set the image for the screen when there is no user logged on. When a user is logged on and locks the screen, it will show my custom image. But when they log off it reverts to a Microsoft spotlight image (some stacked rocks).

I've tried to remedy this by Enabling/Disabling the "Prevent changing lock screen image" and "Always use custom logon background" policies but no configuration seems to make a difference. I also tried changing the image to a local file instead of network.

EDIT: Windows 10 Pro 1511 Update (1607 not installed)

Comment: You should try changing the lock screen image for the default user.

Comment: Which version and edition of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: Ok, a very strange thing. I tried changing the lock screen image for the Administrator account. This fixed the issue seemingly, as when I logged out, the screen was the custom image I wanted. But as soon as I logged in as a domain user, then logged off again, it was back to the Windows image. This domain user has the custom image I want manually set also and shows the correct one when it's logged in.

If I log back in as the Administrator, then log out, same thing occurs. The image I want, but reverted as soon as another user logs in and out.

Comment: @Aquanaut'sHoliday, 6 years on and the same thing happens in Windows 11... it's like the user's personal lock screen settings apply but don't get reverted when the user signs out... so they'll hang around until the next user signs in, or the computer is rebooted.
Not at all what you'd expect to happen.

Did you ever find out how to change the lock screen background permanently?